# How to resolve facebook authentication in android application

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am working on facebook authentication in android application.
I followed all the steps mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/
It is working fine in emulator, but not in android device.
When authenticating with facebook, it doesn't automatically authenticate with facebook app.
Rather it opens facebook login in webview. After login, it gives following error -
"Webpage not available
The webpage at fbconnect://success#access_token... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."
I searched for the problem, created debug key hash,updated debug key hash to facebook app. 
Tried again, same issue.
I created keystore file, created key hash for keystore, updated key hash again to facebook app.
Again same issue.
I unstalled app and reinstalled app. Again same issue.
I disabled facebook app of device, I then run my app, logged in by its authentication webview, and it logged in successfully. Why it is not working with built-in facebook app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a similar message. The built in facebook app justed needed to be updated. Seriously an annoyingly small error to spend so much time on.

Answer (score 1):

**Then, make sure your OAuth redirect URI (e.g. my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler) is listed as one of your OAuth redirect URIs in your Facebook app's settings page on the Facebook for Developers site in the Product Settings > Facebook Login config.**

Maybe this is the reason for  same!

Atleast i was doing this one wrong

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the right "Alias" when generating your keyhash?

Answer (score 0):

Are you Clear about the difference between Android key hash and debug key hash.

and sometimes we face issue in generating key due to openssl missing.

Comment: Yes I know differences, I created both keys in mac os X, I didn't get any error while creating key hash.

Comment: ok , thanks ,
then i think you should wait for some time and check if it is sand box issue

Comment: I disabled facebook app of device, I then run my app, logged in by its authentication webview, and it logged in successfully. Why it is not working with built-in facebook app.

Comment: oh great ,
may be it is facebook's security feature to protect app from fake sessions.